# PHP MAIL: one of my variables send a "false" value

Tags: php

I am sending an e-mail with different variables as an JSON encoded array from an online store. I get the mail just fine and all the data is in there except for one of the variables, which is a JSON encoded array by itself. this particular variable shows as "false" in the e-mail. I'm missing something?

I'm using PHP mail to do it.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

if ($link === false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '" . $_SESSION['logged'] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$user = $_SESSION['logged'];
$rua = $_POST['rua'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];
$apt = $_POST['apt'];
$cep = $_POST['cep'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$comment = $_POST['observacion'];
$from = $row['mail'];
$mailTo = "xxxxx@hotmail.com";
$subject = "compra online - no cep";

$compra = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"];
$compra2 = json_encode($compra);

$bod = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'rua' => $rua,
    'cep' => $cep,
    'compra' => $compra2,
    'comment' => $comment,
    'total' => $total,
);

$body = json_encode($bod);

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $mailTo,
    'Subject' => $subject,
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    'port' => '587',
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => 'xxxxxxx@hotmail.com',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
));

$mail = $smtp->send($mailTo, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo ("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
    header("Location: lojacart.php?mailok");
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

I'm getting the e-mail with all the data except for the `$compra2` variable which is showing as `'compra'=false`. now if I echo the variable `$compra2` it actually have a large string of data on it.

I think it might have to do with the variable being a JSON encoded session, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `json_encode()` returns `FALSE` whenever there was a problem encoding. Take a look at [`json_last_error_msg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see what's actually causing a problem

Comment: [Manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure. Post a *dump* of `$_SESSION["shopping_cart"]`.

Comment: I knew that much, my question is why may be happening... and how can go around it?

Comment: @EstebanLuques we can't help without knowing what is in `$_SESSION["shopping_cart]` my friend.

Comment: @EstebanLuques Tell us what `json_last_error_msg()` says, that will tell you exactly why `json_encode()` is having a problem

Comment: Sessions and JSON encode arent friends and can result in weird outcomes. I'm not sure why anymore (I've encountered it only once, years ago). It's the combination of JSON and SESSION

Comment: well this is weird, until last time the variable had the entire session as a string, now it shows as empty...

Comment: Ok, so... I found out that if I define the compra variable as an array using foreach () , and then json encode it I get it populated BUT only shows the last complete record on the session...

Comment: still it only will send the last record of the array,.. for the guy that voted down on my question... well if you dont know how answer it then is not that simple right ... be mindful about your actions ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying and getting frustrated I came with a solution, for those looking for a something like this:

I added a hidden input to the form on the previous page and assigned it a value as `"print_r($SESSION['whatever you session is called'], TRUE)"` ...

on the next page I took the `$_POST[]` form that input and added the variable to the `$body` array for the mail().

It will print some array garbage in the middle BUT it works like a charm! and I cleaned all the "extra" text form the array using `preg_replace()`. It may not be an elegant way of doing it but as I said... it worked